# How can I run IE with different users and specify a url?

Tags: c#, process, runas

I'm trying to create a console application to replace a batch file. The batch file prompted for a user and ran the following code...

RUNAS /user:USA\%usr% "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe %ServerPath%/%AppName%"

How can I translate this to C# code? I'm basically using the code below. I declare a User Name and a Path, but it always launches IE with my windows login. Am I using Verb incorrectly? Do I need to include a password, and if so, how?

```
string sPath = ServerPath
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
startInfo.Verb = @"runas /user:USA\" + sUser;
startInfo.Arguments = sPath;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function SecureString MakeSecureString(string text)
{
  SecureString secure = new SecureString();
  foreach (char c in text)
  {
    secure.AppendChar(c);
  }

  return secure;
}

function void RunAs(string path, string username, string password)
{
  ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
  myProcess.UserName = username;
  myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
  myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
  Process.Start(myProcess);
}

RunAs(APPLICATION, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Props to [fraser chapman's blog](http://fraserchapman.blogspot.com/2007/07/programmatic-runas-in-c.html)

Comment: IE launches then I get a SecurityRisk page saying "Your security setting level puts your computer at risk". However when running the batch file I do not.

Comment: I assume Windows Vista/7? I would advise trying to run your "Batch simulator" as an administrator and see if that helps.

Comment: Win XP, but adding this fixed it:  myProcess.LoadUserProfile = true;