# C# Process run as different user not working

Tags: c#, process

I want to load a new user profile from a domain.
I start a new process as another user like this :

```
SecureString Secure = new SecureString();
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');

Process RunAs = new Process();
RunAs.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
RunAs.StartInfo.Domain = "mydomain";
RunAs.StartInfo.UserName = "myUser";
RunAs.StartInfo.Password = Secure;
RunAs.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
RunAs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
RunAs.Start();
```

But i have ever the same error : "System.ComponenetModel.Win32Exception : 'Specified file not found'"

I have try to change the StartInfo.FileName with the full path or add a StartInfo.WorkingDirectory, but ever the same error.

The same topic : [Error in Process.Start() — The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369119/error-in-process-start-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)
Say to try with a start info i have try this :

```
SecureString Secure = new SecureString();
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');
Secure.AppendChar('*');

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");

startInfo.Domain = "myDomain";
startInfo.UserName = "myUser";
startInfo.Password = Secure;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But the exception is the same on the last line "Process.Start(startInfo)"
Anybody can help me about that ?

Comment: What line throws that exception? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495596/how-can-i-run-ie-with-different-users-and-specify-a-url help?

Comment: The excpetion is make at the last line "RunAs.Start();"

Comment: Did you try: RunAs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Comment: You can't run as different user with the UserShellExecute = true